# Is there a way to indicate that your PC need a reboot after an upgrade?

Tags: windows, ansible

So I've got a windows 10 iso file and i know that i can start windows Upgrade quietly, now the issue is that Im trying to make the silent upgrade using ansible and ansible need some indication that the upgrade have been done in order to continue to the next task, Is there a way to determine if the windows upgrade have finished and the computer needs a restart? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Never had much joy running Windows updates using Ansible. I moved alot of Windows Tasks away from Ansible and onto SaltStack

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/master/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.win_wua.html